# Use custom email template in another email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

i created an email template in Admin > Marketing > E-Mail Templates like this:

[image: exmpale]

I tried to add to my module email template html by using the template subject like this:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
  <tr> <td> Hello </td> </tr>
</table>

{{trans "Footer"}}
```

my new custom template content wont load, instead it only print plain text `{{trans "Footer"}}`